# How do I pass a "'" as part of an argument to a shell script?

Tags: c#

I have a script which gets executed by Process.Start() within C#.  My script needs a string title to determine what item it needs to work with.  Some of the arguments are titles with a ' in them.

For instance; **My Title's**

When executing as an argument the ' is missing from within the script.  I'm assuming this is being done by C# as calling the same argument from the command line without C# does not remove the ' character.  I've tried to escape the character but it still doesn't work.

```
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\\path\\to\\script.js title's";
```

Thank you for any help,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Throw an @ before your string:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\path\to\script.js title's";
```

[More info here; it's called a verbatim string literal](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-does-an-before-the-start-of-a-string-literal-mean.aspx)